# SQL Server - Normalize Business Hours Data into JSON Object

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, pivot, normalization

My most basic query, when I'm just pulling fields from the database, looks something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  
    [BranchCode]
     ,[Weekday]
     ,[OpenTime]
     ,[CloseTime]
FROM [Departments]
WHERE [BranchCode] like '%1001.0000%'
```

And it gives me a result like this:

```
BranchCode  Weekday     OpenTime    CloseTime
=============================================
1001.0000   Friday      06:00       21:00
1001.0000   Monday      06:00       21:00
1001.0000   Saturday    NULL        NULL
1001.0000   Sunday      NULL        NULL
1001.0000   Thursday    08:00       17:00
1001.0000   Tuesday     08:00       17:00
1001.0000   Wednesday   08:00       17:00
```

#### What I'm trying to achieve

is a JSON *similar* to this result for every BranchCode

```
"1001.0000": {
    "HoursOfOpertion": {
        "Monday": {
            "OpenTime": "06:00",
            "CloseTime": "21:00"
        },
        "Tuesday": {
            "OpenTime": "06:00",
            "CloseTime": "21:00"
        },
        "Wednesday": {
            "OpenTime": "06:00",
            "CloseTime": "21:00"
        },
        "Thursday": {
            "OpenTime": "06:00",
            "CloseTime": "21:00"
        },
        "Friday": {
            "OpenTime": "08:00",
            "CloseTime": "17:00"
        },
        "Saturday": {
            "OpenTime": "NULL",
            "CloseTime": "NULL"
        },
        "Sunday": {
            "OpenTime": "NULL",
            "CloseTime": "NULL"
        }
    }
}
```

#### What I've tried

I've reached a dead end using `PIVOT` and `JOIN`, I feel like I'm close, but I'm still not getting anything close to what I need.

```
SELECT distinct
        [CloseTime]
        ,[Sunday]
        ,[Monday]
        ,[Tuesday]
        ,[Wednesday]
        ,[Thursday]
        ,[Friday]
        ,[Saturday]
FROM [Branches] as br
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT 
        * FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            [Weekday] as [WD]
            ,[OpenTime]
            ,[CloseTime]
            ,[Closed]
            ,[BranchCode]
        FROM [Departments]

    ) AS SRC PIVOT (
        MAX([OpenTime])
            FOR [WD] IN (
        [Sunday]
        ,[Monday]
        ,[Tuesday]
        ,[Wednesday]
        ,[Thursday]
        ,[Friday]
        ,[Saturday]
        )
    ) as PVT
) p
on p.[BranchCode] = br.[BranchCode]
where br.[BranchCode] like '%1001.0000%'
FOR JSON PATH
```

It's giving me something like this:

```
[
    {
        "CloseTime":"1700",
        "Monday":"0800"
    },
    {
        "CloseTime":"1700",
        "Tuesday":"0800"
    },
    {
        "CloseTime":"1700",
        "Wednesday":"0800"
    },
    {
        "CloseTime":"1700",
        "Thursday":"0800"
    },
    {
        "CloseTime":"1700",
        "Friday":"0800"
    },
    {
        "CloseTime":"1800",
        "Saturday":"0800"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two solutions that can get you close.

Sample Data:

```
DECLARE @data TABLE
(
    BranchCode NVARCHAR(100)
    ,WeekDay NVARCHAR(100)
    ,OpenTime NVARCHAR(100)
    ,CloseTime NVARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @data
VALUES
('1001.0000', 'Friday', '06:00', '21:00')
,('1001.0000', 'Monday', '06:00', '21:00')
,('1001.0000', 'Saturday', NULL, NULL)
,('1001.0000', 'Sunday', NULL, NULL)
,('1001.0000', 'Thursday', '08:00', '17:00')
,('1001.0000', 'Tuesday', '08:00', '17:00')
,('1001.0000', 'Wednesday', '08:00', '17:00')
```

The first is more of a dynamic approach but drifts a bit from your intended result, but requires less code.

```
select BranchCode,
    (SELECT 
        WeekDay
        ,OpenTime
        ,CloseTime
     FROM @data dInner
     WHERE dInner.BranchCode = dOuter.BranchCode
     FOR JSON PATH
     ) as [HoursOfOperation]
FROM @data dOuter
FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES, ROOT('Branches')
```

The second is less dynamic but closer to your example. Because SQL uses the table name as the element name, it's difficult to provide a named element for each branch. We can do this for the weekdays because they are a known constant. So essentially you'll just end up with an array of branch objects with a branch code property and the hours of operation. The sample data can be used for this solution as well.

```
select DISTINCT BranchCode,
    (SELECT
        OpenTime
        ,CloseTime
     FROM @data dInner
     WHERE dInner.BranchCode = dOuter.BranchCode and dInner.[WeekDay] = 'Sunday'
     FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
     ) as [HoursOfOperation.Sunday]
     ,(SELECT
        OpenTime
        ,CloseTime
     FROM @data dInner
     WHERE dInner.BranchCode = dOuter.BranchCode and dInner.[WeekDay] = 'Monday'
     FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
     ) as [HoursOfOperation.Monday]
     ,(SELECT
        OpenTime
        ,CloseTime
     FROM @data dInner
     WHERE dInner.BranchCode = dOuter.BranchCode and dInner.[WeekDay] = 'Tuesday'
     FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
     ) as [HoursOfOperation.Tuesday]
     ,(SELECT
        OpenTime
        ,CloseTime
     FROM @data dInner
     WHERE dInner.BranchCode = dOuter.BranchCode and dInner.[WeekDay] = 'Wednesday'
     FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
     ) as [HoursOfOperation.Wednesday]
     ,(SELECT
        OpenTime
        ,CloseTime
     FROM @data dInner
     WHERE dInner.BranchCode = dOuter.BranchCode and dInner.[WeekDay] = 'Thursday'
     FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
     ) as [HoursOfOperation.Thursday]
     ,(SELECT
        OpenTime
        ,CloseTime
     FROM @data dInner
     WHERE dInner.BranchCode = dOuter.BranchCode and dInner.[WeekDay] = 'Friday'
     FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
     ) as [HoursOfOperation.Friday]
     ,(SELECT
        OpenTime
        ,CloseTime
     FROM @data dInner
     WHERE dInner.BranchCode = dOuter.BranchCode and dInner.[WeekDay] = 'Saturday'
     FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
     ) as [HoursOfOperation.Saturday]
FROM @data dOuter
FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES, ROOT('Branches')
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for